# How do you use a parameter in AWS Cloud Formation template instead of an static instance ID?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In an AWS Cloud Formation template, how can you replace the following metric property called "InstanceId", with a value from "Parameters"?

This is what I have tried, but it generates a syntax error. Note 'InstanceIDParm' where I would like the value passed to be used.

```
Description: Test
Parameters:
  InstanceIDParm:
    Description: The idea of the instance to record metric
    Type: String
Resources:
  BasicDashboard:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard
    Properties:
      DashboardName: "Test"
      DashboardBody: '{
    "widgets": [
        {
          "type":"metric",
          "width": 15,
          "height": 8,
          "properties":{
              "metrics":[
                [ "AWS/EC2", "CPUUtilization", "InstanceId", "!Ref InstanceIDParm" ]
            ]
        }
    ]
  }'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following syntax should work:

**Params:**

```
Parameters:
  InstanceIDParm:
    Description: The idea of the instance to record metric
    Type: String
```

**Usage:**

```sh
  [ "AWS/EC2", "CPUUtilization", "InstanceId", "${InstanceIDParm}" ]
```

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html):

> A string with variables that AWS CloudFormation substitutes with their
> associated values at runtime. **Write variables as ${MyVarName}.
> Variables can be template parameter names, resource logical IDs,
> resource attributes, or a variable in a key-value map**. If you specify
> only template parameter names, resource logical IDs, and resource
> attributes, don't specify a key-value map.
>
> If you specify template parameter names or resource logical IDs, such
> as ${InstanceTypeParameter}, AWS CloudFormation returns the same
> values as if you used the Ref intrinsic function. If you specify
> resource attributes, such as ${MyInstance.PublicIp}, AWS
> CloudFormation returns the same values as if you used the Fn::GetAtt
> intrinsic function.
>
> To write a dollar sign and curly braces (${}) literally, add an
> exclamation point (!) after the open curly brace, such as ${!Literal}.
> AWS CloudFormation resolves this text as ${Literal}.